# Compiling COBOL as 32-bit Executable For Windows

Tags: windows, compilation, cobol, 16-bit

I am diving into the world of COBOL and have written a simple program that compiles and runs as intended from my KDE Plasma command line using open-cobol (cobc). I have seen a few sites mention that COBOL is quite portable and does not require multiple compilations, but when I try to run the same output program on Windows 10 (ie 32-bit), the system states that the program is a 16-bit application and thus cannot run.

Are there parameters that I can use with cobc to compile in such a way that my programs will run on Windows 10, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding the portability of this language?

Compilation command: `cobc -x -o program program.cob`

Comment: *COBOL is quite portable* is true. That doesn't mean that Open-COBOL is, though. Have you checked the [documentation](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/doc/gnucobol.html), which tells you what is possible when compiling? Did you compile on a 32-bit OS?

Comment: The source code is likely compatible, but the binary files aren't. That doesn't mean you can take an opencobol program written to run on Linux and copy that binary to windows and have it run. You'd have tot take the source to the Windows machine and install opencobol (or other Cobol compiler) there. Compile your program and run it. By compatibility they mean source compatibility. Different Cobol compilers on Windows could probably produce a similar functioning program for Windows.

Comment: Effectively for every OS you will likely need to recompile your programs, but with luck you don't have to modify the source to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is likely already a 64bit executable (depending on your actual OS, otherwise its 32bit), but it is definitely no Windows binary (and because Windows doesn't recognize it, it just guesses this is a 16bit executable).

COBOL itself *is* portable, even between different compilers (*if* you restrict yourself to "standard" COBOL or use only the extensions that the compilers used share), but you need "some" native parts in any case.
As a well known example take Java or .NET: the "runtime" is a native binary, which executes the java (or msil) byte code.

There are some COBOL compilers generating intermediate code which is actually portable and can be used with the "native runtime" you have to install beforehand.

The easiest option for your case: take a compatible compiler and recompile your COBOL source for this platform on this platform.
I'd suggesting the successor of OpenCOBOL: [GnuCOBOL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnucobol/), using the [official windows binaries](https://www.arnoldtrembley.com/GnuCOBOL.htm).